# How to dynamically populate Gravity Forms select menus items from different columns in Google Sheets data

Tags: php, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

I'm trying to populate the options available for selection in a dropdown using data from google sheets. I've found this code that is working just fine, but I want the column name to be dynamic and based on the input from another field.

```
$location_form_id = '21';
add_filter( 'gform_pre_render_'.$location_form_id, 'populate_posts' );
add_filter( 'gform_pre_validation_'.$location_form_id, 'populate_posts' );
add_filter( 'gform_pre_submission_filter_'.$location_form_id, 'populate_posts' );
add_filter( 'gform_admin_pre_render_'.$location_form_id, 'populate_posts' );


function populate_posts( $form ) {

    //the select feild id you want the names to load
    $field_ID = 'FIELD_ID_HERE';
    //your g sheet ID
    $gSheet_form_ID = 'SHEET_ID_HERE';
    // which column to scan - what is the heading name
    $column_name = 'COLUMN_HEADING_NAME_HERE';
    $placeholder = 'YOUR_PLACEHOLDER_HERE';
    $list_number = '1';


    //get data
    $url = 'https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/'.$gSheet_form_ID.'/'.$list_number.'/public/values?alt=json';
    
    $file = file_get_contents($url);
    $json = json_decode($file);
    $rows = $json->{'feed'}->{'entry'};


    //get all the same from sheet
    $names = array(); //store names in this array
    foreach($rows as $row) {
        $name = $row->{'gsx$'.$column_name}->{'$t'};
        array_push($names, $name); //push data
    }
    
    //Go through each form fields
    foreach ( $form['fields'] as $field ) {
        //check if field type is a select dropdown and id is correct
        if ( $field->type == 'select' && $field->id == $field_ID) {
            //add name and value to the option
            foreach($names as $single_name){
                $choices[] = array('text' => $single_name, 'value' => $single_name );
            }
            //Add a place holder
            $field->$placeholder;
            //Add the new names to the form choices
            $field->choices = $choices;
            // Print out the contents of the array (troubleshooting only)
            //echo '<pre>'; print_r($choices); echo '</pre>';
        }
    }
    return $form; //return form
}
```

How can I edit this code so that `$column_name =` whatever input is in Field 1 to show different selections in Field 2 from a google sheets column.